# Rewrite dynamic url structure with .hataccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, sef

I've tried to rewrite the dynamic URL (below) to a slightly different structure; either does not work or I am not sure if it is correct:

- Old URL (URL#1): index.php?lang=AAA&zone=BBB&city=CCC&str=DDD&search=EEE
- New URL (URL#11): index.php?lang=AAA&country=BBB&place=CCC&street=DDD

*basically changed the names and the "search" string is not important any more

- what I am trying to achieve is redirecting all visitors from (old) dynamic URL#1 to (new) dynamic URL#11

In a second step, after all search engines show the new urls and we finished all test that are easier with non-sef urls, we would like to rewrite URL#11 to URL#2

- New URL (URL#11): index.php?lang=AAA&country=BBB&place=CCC&street=DDD
- Sef URL (URL#2): /AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD

I am not very familiar with apache programming and even when my solution works, we are not sure if it is the right one or if it will generate errors with certain URLs. Any help would be highly appreciated in creating a .htaccess file that does the step 1 redirection and a separate .htaccess file to be used later, for SEF urls. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `http://example.com/index.php?lang=AAA&zone=BBB&city=CCC&str=DDD&search=EEE`
>
> redirected to:
>
> `http://example.com/AAA/BBB/CCC/DDD`
>
> silently mapped to:
>
> `http://example.com/index.php?lang=AAA&country=BBB&place=CCC&street=DDD`

You may try this in one .htacces file in root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=([^&]+)&zone=([^&]+)&city=([^&]+)&str=([^&]+)&search=  [NC]
RewriteRule .* /%1/%2/%3/%4?   [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php                          [NC]
RewriteRule .* /index.php?lang=%1&country=%2&place=%3&street=%4 [L,NC]
```

If the query contains parameters in this format: `%nn`, try adding the  **B** flag to both rules. Example: [L,NC,B].

Comment: This one Did the job! We figured that some changes in the php script are needed as well and not possible via .htaccess only. However, your suggested method is working, thank you!

`Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=([^&]+)&zone=([^&]+)&city=([^&]+)&str=([^&]+)&search=  [NC]
RewriteRule .* /index.php?lang=%1&country=%2&place=%3&street=%4 [L,NC]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variables only ever consist of lowercase letters and digits, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$
    /index.php?lang=$1&country=$2&place=$3&street=$4
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}
    ^lang=([a-z0-9]+)&zone=([a-z0-9]+)&city=([a-z0-9]+)&str=([a-z0-9]+)&search=[a-z0-9]+$
RewriteRule ^index.php$
    /index.php?lang=%1&country=%2&place=%3&street=%4 [R=permanent]
```

(Note that there must be **no line breaks**, but I've inserted them here with indents just to make the block readable on this webpage.)

Comment: Unfortunately, the URLs are both upper and lower -case and spaces (%20) as well, even punctuation marks like dashes, periods, hyphens and plus signs:

- index.php?lang=en&zone=Zone109&city=229MIA%20Florida&str=7800%20NW%205th%20Ct%20bl.%2021,%2022,%2022A

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked (first step), from [faa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679045/faa):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=([^&]+)&zone=([^&]+)&city=([^&]+)&str=([^&]+)&search=  [NC]
RewriteRule .* /index.php?lang=%1&country=%2&place=%3&street=%4 [L,NC]
```