# Htaccess to rewrite url for an existing php app

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have developed a PHP application and I want to rewrite the URLs to make it cleaner,
I have multiple pages, each page can have 0 or multiple GET variables,

Example of what I want to achieve:

index.php   ->   /

/index.php?var1=aaa&var2=bbb&var3=ccc   ->   /var1/aaa/var2/bbb/var3/ccc

/product.php?var4=ddd&var5=eee   ->   /product/var4/ddd/var5/eee

/products-list.php   ->   /products-list/

etc...

Can anyone help me with a full .htaccess file to achieve this result?
And is there a way to make the PHP read the GET params or do I need to add a function to create a $_GET array from the URL on each page?

Thank you.

Comment: The `_GET` superglobal variable is automatically filled for you, no need for any function of such., assuming that you actually specific get variables in your rewrite target.

Comment: You will find hundreds of working examples for rewriting path tokens to get variables. I am sure you can start implementing your own solution. You will need three or four rules, a separate one for each number of variables. Put the more specialized rules atop, more general rules below. If you have issues getting things to work, _then_ is the time to come here and ask. Posting your own implementation attempt in the question and also a precise explanation what exactly does not work as expected.

Comment: @arkascha can you share a link with me to a working example?

Comment: Investing 10 secs into looking through the "Related"  section on the right hand side brought up that one as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622846/rewrite-dynamic-url-structure-with-hataccess?rq=1

Comment: @arkascha I've already searched and tried to implement multiple examples with no luck, the example in the link you shared assumes that the name of the variables is not dynamic, my variables can have any name, and also I have multiple pages, not only index.php

Comment: Sure, but you can see how a regular expression is used to capture tokens of the requested URL and how those tokens are again used to assemble the rewriting target, right? So what keeps you from doing that?

Comment: I added a simple example as answer below.

Answer (score 1):

These simple rules will rewrite the examples you give in the question:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteEngine ^/?products-list/?$ /products-list.php [QSA,END]
RewriteRule ^/?product/([^/+])/([^/+])/([^/+])/([^/+])/?$ /product.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [QSA,END]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/+])/([^/+])/([^/+])/([^/+])/([^/+])/([^/+])/?$ /index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [QSA,END]
```

You might have to add some conditions to prevent interference with other rules or rewriting loops. But that is nothing we can know without insight into your specific situation and setup.